# Playing sound when new message comes in

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, audio

I am making chat for my student group, and I am using AJAX to get my messages like this

```
//Initial call i make so user do not wait 2 seconds for messages to show
function marko() {
    $("#porukice").load("messages.php"); //Load the content into the div
}

marko();

//autorefresh every 2 seconds
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
(function () {
    $("#porukice").load("messages.php"); //Load the content into the div
}), 2000);
```

To send messages I am also using ajax, like this

```
var frm = $('#form1');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById("message").value = "";
                document.getElementById('play').play();
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
```

This is part of message.php (where messages are generated)

```
$sql = $conn->query('(SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY time desc limit 0, 10) ORDER BY time');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row){ 
    $time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($row['2']));
    echo '['.$time.'] <b>'.$row['0'].'</b>: '.stripslashes($row['1'])."<br/>";
}
```

I am trying to play a sound when new message arrives>
only solution I came up with is to play a sound when message is sent with

```
document.getElementById('play').play();
```

as you can see in above code. I have no clue how to play it when messages are coming, when mysql row is updated.
I saw other answers on stackoverflow but they are not helping me.

**NOTICE:** `$row['1']` is message, `$row['0']` is user name and `$row['2']` is time.

Comment: Sorry If i confused you with question, this is best I can do to explain.
Also, as you can see in sql query, i set time for each message so maybe somehow I can do it with time value? It's just a idea, i still don't know how to do that.

Comment: Just for your knowledge: for this is better not to use Ajax but a web socket or node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by creating separate file called `sound.php`
`Sound.php` is answering to get request with json response including date and time of last message

```
{"last_time":"2017-02-25 17:45:55"}
```

Then I am calling this file every 2 seconds with ajax, and if last_time has changed i play a sound

```
var skipped_once = false;
var old_time = 0

var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
$.get("sound.php", function(data) {
            // if old_time different than last_time play sound
        if (old_time != data.last_time) {
            //do not play sound on first page load
            if (skipped_once) {
                document.getElementById('play').play(); 
out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
            }
            skipped_once = true;
            old_time = data.last_time;       
        }
    });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass, from the PHP script that gets the messages, the value of the last id you got. Then, store it in a jQuery variable, and after you reload the messages, check if the ids are different, if they are (that means a new message came up), play the sound.

For example, after the `foreach` loop:

```
return json_encode(array('last_time' => $rows[count($rows)-1][2]));
```

On your jQuery:

```
var last_time = 0; // <--- New
var new_time = 0; // <--- New

// Initial call i make so user do not wait 2 seconds for messages to show
function marko() {
    $("#porukice").load("messages.php"); //Load the content into the div

    // New
    if (last_time < new_time) {
        document.getElementById('play').play(); 
        last_time = new_time;       
    }
}

marko();

//autorefresh every 2 seconds
setInterval(function () { // <--- Some edits here
    marko(); // <--- Some edits here
}, 2000);

// ....

var frm = $('#form1');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("message").value = "";

            last_time = new_time; // <--- New
            new_time = data.last_time; // <--- New
        }
    });

    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

I've not tested this, but you're free to do it and let me know.

**EDITED to use `time` instead of `id`**

Comment: The moment when i send message it just goes playing sound over and over again.

Comment: Maybe i should tell you that mesages.php are displaying only 10 last messages so it will be always 10.
If i properly understood your try you wanted to do this by message count.

Comment: After playing the sound, make new_id = last_id

Comment: I am not such a programmer. but i think that response i get from return `json_encode(array('last_id' => $rows[count($rows)-1]));`

Will always be 9

Comment: True, change it for `$rows[count($rows)-1]['id']` or whatever name you use to identify your messages' id

Comment: I do not have message id, now i understand what you were trying to do.
I have only time.

Comment: You can use time too,  it's the same. Anyway you should identify your messages with unique ids

Comment: You forgot to change last_id to last_time in reutrn

Comment: You are great guy, i'm gonna test it out and let you know.

Comment: Doesn't work :( i do not know why. Here you can see my js http://www.leochat.info/assets/js/chat.js
You can register http://www.leochat.info and see what's going on if you want. Cuz i dont

Comment: NO, I can just say that when i check RESPONSE of ajax reload for messages.php i see NO json code. Are you sure return can be used? Because file is not required or included, file is called via ajax on refresh as you saw in js code.
This is response 
 `<a href='#' id='2017-02-24 14:07:05' class='trash'>Delete</a> [14:07:05] <b><a href='profile.php?name=INFO'>INFO</a></b>: Chat log has been pruned<br/><a href='#' id='2017-02-24 14:07:48' class='trash'>Delete</a> [14:07:48] <b><a href='profile.php?name=Luka'>Luka</a></b>: da<br/> `

Comment: I will set bounty tomorrow and give it to you if you help me please

Comment: I'm looking at it. Try yourself tweaking the code too.

Comment: You're right, instead of `return json_encode(array('last_time' => $rows[count($rows)-1][2]));`, use `echo json_encode(array('last_time' => $rows[count($rows)-1][2]));` or `die(json_encode(array('last_time' => $rows[count($rows)-1][2])));`

Comment: This just displays time on the bottom of div `porukice` like this
`{"last_time":"2017-02-24 16:02:59"}`
And it doesn't work... Maybe i need to create separate file with json response header and then call it from ajax? But how to call it...

Comment: In your AJAX request, change `success: function (data)` to `success: function(response)` and right before (or after) `document.getElementById("message").value = "";`, add: `var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);`

Comment: You realize that you are adding code to form1 which has nothing to do with messages.php?
That is just sending post requests to home.php so it insert in database message. that is all. You need response from messages.php not home.php
Or am I wrong?

Comment: The response from `messages.php` is the `json_encode`. You're sending back some data, and need to parse it if the AJAX's request is successful.

Comment: I tried what you said, it is not working again :(
I am doomed. http://www.leochat.info/assets/js/chat.js